# Firebase Process is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

firebae.jsx

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();

export const register = async (email, password) => {
  const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  return user;
};

export default app;
```

.env.development

```
 REACT_APP_API_KEY= A*************
```

how can i described process. it s give me error message. i cant fix it it.

Comment: all of your .env variables is working ? Did you console it ?

Comment: you use vite???

Comment: yes i used vite